# File downloading with user-adjustable filename and download location

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, download

I am working on a web application that needs the feature of being able to download files after they are saved to a database. The user should have full control of the file location and change the file name.

I have been scouring the internet to figure out if there is a way to allow the user to input both the filename and then determine the file location, similar to how on Google when you download something you pick the name and then can select a location of where to download it. I have seen a lot of approaches that handle downloading but do not allow inputted filenames and file paths which is a necessity for my application.

I am not familiar with anything like this so if someone has even a completely different direction that would allow for my needed features any help would be appreciated!

The code I have so far for just downloading a file is not working because VS is not liking the response method calls and the Server.MapPath:

```cs
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var file = Request.QueryString("file");
    var hasFile = !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(file);

    if (!hasFile)
        return;

    var hasFileExists = File.Exists(Server.MapPath(file));
    if (!hasFileExists)
        return;

    var filepath = Server.MapPath(file);
    var filename = Path.GetFileName(filepath);
    var contentType = GetContentType(filepath);


    var hasValidFileExtension = IsValidFileExtension(filepath);
    var hasReadyForDownLoad = hasValidFileExtension && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filename) && !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(contentType);

    if (!hasReadyForDownLoad)
        return;

    HttpResponse response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    response.ClearContent();
    response.ContentType = contentType;
    response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "Attachment; filename=" + filename + ";");
    response.TransmitFile(filepath);
    response.Flush();
    response.End();

}

// get content type
private string GetContentType(string filepath)
{
    var contentType = "application/octetstream";
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(filepath);

    RegistryKey registryKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(extension);

    if (registryKey != null && registryKey.GetValue("Content Type") != null)
        contentType = registryKey.GetValue("Content Type").ToString();

    return contentType;
}

// check is file have valid extension
private bool IsValidFileExtension(string file)
{
    bool isValidFileExtension = false;

    string[] FileExtensions = new string[] { "lic" };


    string extension = Path.GetExtension(file).TrimStart('.');

    if (FileExtensions.Contains(extension, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        isValidFileExtension = true;
    }

    return isValidFileExtension;
}
```

Comment: Note sure why or how testing for a valid extension on the WEB SERVER going to matter on the client side? You simply can't set the file location from the server side. This is 100% based on the user's browser settings. You have ZERO means to control this. Some browsers let you pick the location, but that will be hit or miss. You can't decide to download some .exe file into my computers program files, you can't know or determine ANY thing about my computer and even my folders existing or not.  If you could mess with my computer from a browser, the no one would risk using the internet.

Comment: Most browsers will default a download to the "download" folder, and what occurs is going to be the settings and the kind of browser the user chooses. It simply not your choice. So, some browsers will let you specify a path, but often it will be ignored, and comes down to the users browser (say on Android phone), or whatever. You can't know, and you can't choose the file location for the end user. If you seen a prompt, then that was due to your browser settings, and not the server side code.

Comment: That makes complete sense, thank you for that information.  The reasoning for testing for valid extension is because the DLL that is connected to my application only uses .lic files so I need to ensure those are the only files that my web application downloads. 

Do you have any insight based on my approach on how to allow the client to determine the filename and then taking that file name and downloading the file or is that handled by the browser as well?

Comment: Quite sure the "save as" prompt is a browser setting. If not set, then the file just goes into the download files folder. (assuming a windows computer, since iPad, Android etc. don't have the same kind of folders and structure as windows computers.  You can actually try including a path name in the file name setting, and often that does work, but again, that's going to be on a per browser basis.  However, do fix that ffilename and change it to filename. That then at least should result in your server code setting the file name.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by fixing the ffilename and changing it to filename? That naming convention is not in my code. 

Also, do you have any input regarding the rest of the method structure or any other ideas about how I can go about ensuring a file download will work? Is my approach on target?

Comment: Yes, either you code or post been fixed, or edited. You had this: "Attachment; ffilename=". So there was 2 "ff" at the start of that, and the correct syntax is filename=.  So, your code now looks correct. That file name thus should be JUST a file name without a path. You can as noted try adding the path name, as some browsers still seem to allow use of path name, and thus the default download will not go to the downloads folder. However, I would test/get this working with JUST supplying the file name for filename=. So, when I first viewed your post, you had ffilename= in place of filename

Comment: Is there any reason you have to use asp.net which is out dated？ Better to use asp.net core for new project.

Comment: I am using asp.net core I mislabeled the tabs.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing around the logic of how I was going about downloading the file, but here is a working solution that downloads on button click:

```
 public IActionResult OnPostDownloadFile()
{
    string fileName = "ScanDeviceLicense.lic";

    string filePath = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "wwwroot", fileName);

    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return File(new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read), "application/octet-stream", fileName);

}
```